# When I am shifting are the numbers in Two´s complement and iee745?

Tags: java, ieee-754

my question is, that when we are shifting we say for example:

```
10<<2  is (10=1010 <<2= 101000)
```

But at the same time, a lot of people says, we need to make a difference between negative and positive numbers by shifting. But how? For example, when I would have -10, and I will shift this number, is that number before and after shifting in the twos complement?

And the same for floating point numbers, when I am shifting for example 1.0<<2,  is the 1.0 in iee745, if yes  I delete binary numbers with every shift?

This is 1.0 in twos complement `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`

So when we sayy

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 <<2  it will be to--> 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111100? So my number will be smaller or?
```

So so we can say shifting only increases the number if it is not in iee754 format?

Comment: You cannot shift doubles and floats. And  _"This is 1.0 in twos complement `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` "_: this is wrong, `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` is **-1** in twos complement.

Comment: Thank you brother.